# Como faço pesquisa em matrizes?

Tags: python, matriz

Eu tenho que fazer um programa no qual eu tenho que informar um valor dentro de uma matriz e depois imprimir todos os elementos dentro dessa lista.
ex:

```
lista = [['airbus',35 ,522]['gol',34,225]]

print("\nQual aeronave ou fabricante deseja pesquisar?")

pesq = int(input("\nInsira o codigo internacional do fabricante:\n"))
      

pesquisar(pesq)

def pesquisar(pesq):
```

retornar:

O primeiro : airbus

O segundo é: 35

O terceiro é: 522

já usei for junto com if, mas não funcionou.
ajuda?

Answer (score -3):

Olá, talvez o mais interessante para o seu caso utilizar os dicionários, em vez de uma lista, pois você deseja buscar por dados a partir de uma chave específica. Em listas você deve saber a posição por isso que o método acaba necessitando de um algoritmo de busca. Mas caso você possa implementar de uma outra forma o ideal seria armazenar as informações em um dicionário em que a chave é o nome da aeronave ou fabricante.

Eu tenho um repositório que explica um pouco sobre lógica de programação com Python, lá há uma seção específica sobre dicionários: [link do repositório](https://github.com/Regijur/LogicaDeProgramacao)

Caso o intuito seja utilizar matrizes mesmo, então você pode buscar o valor digitado sempre pelo primeiro elemento de cada elemento da matriz, e quando encontrar a posição correta você imprime todos os elementos daquela lista.

Por exemplo:

```
def imprimir_elementos(matriz, elemento_buscado):
   achou = False
   i = 0
   while not achou and i < len(matriz):
      if matriz[i][0] == elemento_buscado:
         achou = True
      else:
         i += 1

   if achou:
      for elemento in matriz[i]:
          print(elemento)
   else:
      print("Elemento não encontrado")
```